# OverScrollDecoratorHelper get onOverScrollUpdate callback from view

Tags: android, overscroll

I'm using "me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4". 
Can I get offset value from image view, that i trying to swipe down?
Documentation says
OverScrollDecoratorHelper.setUpStaticOverScroll(view, OverScrollDecoratorHelper.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
My code is

```
@BindView(R.id.swipeDownImgV)
ImageView swipeDownImgV;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_orders_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    setUpSwipeListener();

    return view;
}

private void setUpSwipeListener() {

    OverScrollDecoratorHelper.setUpStaticOverScroll(swipeDownImgV, OverScrollDecoratorHelper.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL)
            .setOverScrollUpdateListener(new IOverScrollUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onOverScrollUpdate(IOverScrollDecor decor, int state, float offset) {
                    Log.d(Tag.SWIPE, offset + " offset");
                }
            });
```

But it has no effect, what I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Need just put image in ScrollView

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/swipeDownContainerScrlV"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/v16dp"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:src="@drawable/no_order_swipe_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</ScrollView>
```

D/SWIPE: 2.3315098 offset

D/SWIPE: 5.9953127 offset

D/SWIPE: 8.992973 offset

D/SWIPE: 10.325269 offset

D/SWIPE: 11.990633 offset